# meta riddling with jokers

Tags: riddle, rhyme

*Riddle me this,

riddle me that..

Do I have a hat?*

*My name is enygma

my heart is my brain.

But what’s my domain?*

*I’ll give you a joker

to finish the game,

me and my questions are not the same.*

*Now for my last question.

Oh, what a twiddle!

and then you’ll have to answer Minotaur’s riddle.*

*What is the nickname

of my toughest foe?

(Don’t forget the joker, tho!)*

Let's play. I'm looking for 4 answers ( the 3 questions stated in the riddle + who is the riddler?)

Comment: riddler is zlobi.wan.kenobi :)

Comment: ha! :) the other, meta-riddler is wanted here.. Too much meta.. I started to even confuse myself

Comment: All I know is that the entire thing has The Riddler all over them. (Edward Nygma) but I'm not sure what it is we are supposed to find...

Comment: there are 3 questions in the riddle, this is obvious, since they are unambiguous marked with question mark. You are supposed to find the answer of these 3 questions + the identity of the person who is making the riddle (and that's not me, that's why it is meta-riddling).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are:

> **Edward Nygma** (The Riddle (Enygma), from Batman)

Riddle me this,
riddle me that..
Do I have a hat?

> Yes, it is a green bowler hat.

My name is enygma
my heart is my brain.
But what’s my domain?

> Gotham City (DC Comics)

I’ll give you a joker
to finish the game,
me and my questions are not the same.

> Is this a question? I don't think so.

Now for my last question.
Oh, what a twiddle!
and then you’ll have to answer Minotaur’s riddle.

> **Minotaur**: I have millions of eyes, yet I live in darkness. I have    millions of ears, yet only four lobes. I have no muscles, yet
>
>  I rule    two hemispheres. What am I?
>
>   **Batman**: That's simple: the human brain.
>
>   **Batman**: It has millions of visual and auditory nerves, four lobes,    two hemispheres, and it's the only thing Edward Nygma
>
>  respects.

What is the nickname
of my toughest foe?
(Don’t forget the joker, tho!)

> "Batsy" - Joker's favourite nickname of Batman

Comment: @MarkN Thx for the edit, I always have trouble with hiding large responses, didn't realize I could use HTML element "<br>"!

Comment: You can add 2 spaces at the end of the line. It does the same thing as a BR tag

Comment: @Daedric np, I never knew it either until someone edited one of my posts ;)

Comment: it seems, the riddle was pretty easy this time :) your answer contains 3 of the 4 answers. Do you need a hint for it?

Comment: @zlobi.wan.kenobi Sure what am I missing :)

Comment: The nickname of my toughest foe. think about it as the nickname someone else uses for the toughest foe.. more jokers? :)

Comment: Red Hood? Else im stummped, Arch Enemy

Comment: Are you saying its a nickname of the Joker?

Comment: Is it a reference to this song: "Ace of Spades"

Comment: Could it be a common nickname for one's toughest foe, like *rival*?

Comment: Maybe Nemesis? or arch-rival

Comment: @zlobi.wan.kenobi Its so confusing maybe you can shed some more light on the correct answer? Is it even related to a character or some other reference. It seems no one can figure this out are you sure the answer fits the question??

Comment: It's a nickname of Batman, as you already guessed. The question is, which nickname of Batman. The clue gives you a clue, who uses the nickname I am searching for. :) Hope this helps.

Comment: @zlobi.wan.kenobi I added a "few" more~!!

Comment: yes, it is in the list :) the Joker's favourite nickname of Batman.

Comment: @zlobi.wan.kenobi Cool, nice riddle.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly over-doing the meta layer, and ignoring the obvious batman-related answer, the one posing the riddle is:

> The Minotaur

Riddle me this,/
riddle me that../
Do I have a hat?

> Nope. Horns, though

My name is enygma/
my heart is my brain./
But what’s my domain?

> The Labyrinth (on Crete, I think?). Though this clue kinda makes me think of The Wizard of Oz

I’ll give you a joker/
to finish the game,/
me and my questions are not the same.

> This is what makes me think it's not Batman related, which means we need another famous riddler

Now for my last question./
Oh, what a twiddle!/
and then you’ll have to answer Minotaur’s riddle.

> Seems overly straightforward, but if this is 'Minotaur's riddle', then are you not the minotaur?

What is the nickname/
of my toughest foe?/
(Don’t forget the joker, tho!)

> That'd be Theseus, then. Can't think of any nicknames off-hand

Comment: It smells like Batman. I shouldn't have put so much clues there. The last line does not match with the joker-clue, but apart from that, very logical.